# Publish a library to maven repositories

Tags: maven-2, repository, dependencies, publishing

I have a stable [opensource library](http://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe) and was wondering how (and if) I can publish my lib to maven official repositories so people can include it in their `pom.xml` files and get the dependency downloaded automatically.

Comment: Since this is the Java world, it will of course be 20 times less obvious than publishing `npm` packages for JavaScript.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The process to get your library in the central repostiory is documented in the [Guide to uploading artifacts to the Central Repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html). In short, the **new** process is to get your project hosted by one of the approved Forges that will be synced with  central, the Maven folks don't rsync personal repository anymore. In your case, your best bet would be to use the [Sonatype Forge](http://nexus.sonatype.org/oss-repository-hosting.html) (open to any OSS Project). Check the given link (and also [this document](https://docs.sonatype.com/display/NX/OSS+Repository+Hosting)).

Comment: Take a look to the [Sonatype OSS Maven Repository Usage Guide](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide).

Comment: This blog post helped me to do it - http://zserge.com/blog/gradle-maven-publish.html

Comment: From the Sonatype OSS guide: "1. Create your JIRA account.  2. Create a new project ticket.  This triggers creation of your repositories. Normally, the process takes less than 2 business days."  LOLOLOLOLOLOL

Answer (score 4):

If you want reliable access for everyone out there, you need to stick with [central](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html). Due to the tendency of people at dev.java.net to break rules about the immutability of released artifacts, some people don't trust it. Further, it can be Very Slow.

To get your project into central, you need have your code in some public repo that they can sync from.

Comment: You can't get a personal repository synced with central anymore, the new process is to use an approved forge.

Answer (score 2):

- [Central repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html)
- A bit less bureaucratic [dev.java.net Maven2 repository](https://maven2-repository.dev.java.net/) - allows completely automatic deployment.