# Maven dependency for the jar of github maven project

Tags: git, maven, github

I created a maven [project](https://github.com/devender-yadav/GitUserDetailsFinder) on github. I want to create a **maven dependency** for the jar of this project.

How to do that? Do I need to change `pom.xml`?

Comment: Do you mean you want other people to be able to include your project as a dependency in their Maven builds? Then you need to publish the compiled jar file in a Maven repository.

Comment: @Thilo How to publish the compiled jar in a Maven repository?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588858/publish-a-library-to-maven-repositories http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013644/hosting-a-maven-repository-on-github?rq=1